# Java check every 1hour

Tags: android, android-event

i build a server that sends questions to  clients depending on the cells they are in, for example if they are in Rome's cell, the server will send them questions different from the questions will be sent to clients in London's cell, and when a question be sent to a client, the server will make it as unavailable to the cell for one hour, i mean that question will never be sends to any client in that cell for one hour

and my question is how can i make java method for make that question is available after one hour?

#### EDIT1:

i have a hashtable , the keys are the cells, and the values are the question asked in these cells

#### EDIT2

this is the hashtable

```
static Hashtable<Integer, List<Integer>> unavialbeQuestions;
```

and when i asked question in a cell i make this

```
unavialbeQuestions.get(cellID).add(questionID);
```

and i want something like this

```
function makeQuestionAvailable(int questionID, int cellID){}
```

Comment: Are you using a database for questions and clients? or what? please share some server details.

Comment: @djaqeel yes i am using databases to save question , cells, clients and so many details , but tell me what kind of details do you want, i am sure u don't need database diagram,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can schedule methods to run after desired amount of time has passed using `Timer` class. Have a look at this example for details:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html

**EDIT1:**

Call this function fter an hour:

```
function makeQuestionAvailable(int questionID, int cellID){
     unavialbeQuestions.get(cellID).remove(questionID);
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Example code fro scheduling:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       Timer timer = new Timer();

       timer.schedule(new ScheduledTaskWithHandeler(), 5000);

    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {

       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Run!",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    };

    class ScheduledTaskWithHandeler extends TimerTask {

       @Override
       public void run() {
          handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
       }
    }
```

Comment: i will check that link thank you , but please would you see my edit

Comment: after edit2: i know how can i remove elements from hashtable, but how can i make your function starts after 1hour from putting the question in the hashtable? and thank you for answering

Comment: see edit2, it should be similar to that. that code schedules a task to run 5seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

When using Android generally speaking you should use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class rather than a timer, especially if you're doing this in the background, TimerTasks are prone to being killed by the OS.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679367/timer-task-vs-alarm-manager-usage-in-android-service)