# What to use: AlarmManger or my own service with Timer (scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period));

Tags: android, alarmmanager

in my case i have to do a task lets say every 5 min in next 3hour. Which one would be better AlarmManger or Timer. In case of AlarmManger i will be starting an intent service which will do the task and in later one i will use TimerTask. Moreover how will get pending intent to use AlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) in intentService onHandleIntent.

possible copy of this, but have different scenario. [Timer Task VS Alarm Manager usage in Android Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679367/timer-task-vs-alarm-manager-usage-in-android-service)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up:

```
Intent i = new Intent( context.getApplicationContext(), NameOfYourClass.class );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( c.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0 );
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
am.setRepeating( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5*60*1000, pi ); 
// ELAPSED_REALTIME will execute ONLY when phone is awake, to execute always use ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
```

Just after this initial setup save when counter started: , ex. [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html)

Finally, when the time comes:

```
Intent i = new Intent( context.getApplicationContext(), NameOfYourClass.class );
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( context.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0 );
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
am.cancel( pi );
```

Comment: hi thanks it worked, just one thing that if you plan to use intentservice the before am.setRepeating use PendingIntent.getService() instead of getbroadcast. Thanks