# TimerTask only triggers once

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I set up the TimerTask UpdateTask but it only fires once at the when I start my program.  Why doesn't it continue to trigger?

Some of the methods here are in other classes, if you need them, don't hesitate to let me know.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class graphpanel extends variables
{
Timer timer = new Timer();

int ypoint;
int barheight;

int height = getHeight();
int width = getWidth();
int bars = (int)getLife() - (int)getAge();
int xpoint = 0;
int barwidth = 20;

public graphpanel()
{
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTask(), 10);
}


public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < bars; i++)
    {
        barheight = (int) getTime(i)/100;
        ypoint = height/2 - barheight;
        g.drawRect(xpoint, ypoint, barwidth, barheight);
        g.drawString("hey", 10*i, 40);
    }
}

class UpdateTask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        bars = (int)getLife() - (int)getAge();
        System.out.print("TimerTask detected");
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would Alarm Manager not be more appropriate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679367/timer-task-vs-alarm-manager-usage-in-android-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)` only schedules the task for one-time execution.

Use

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTask(), 10, 10);
```

for repeating invocations of your `TimerTask`.

More info: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

[scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,Date firstTime,long period)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

(or)

[schedule((TimerTask task,Date firstTime,long period))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

10 in your `schedule()` method call is `delay`, not `period`.